# Extraña salida usando búferes

Tags: c, búfer, stdout

Estaba probando cosas con los búferes y me preguntaba por qué el siguiente programa tiene esta salida tan rara:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE* fp;
    char mybuffer[512];

    setvbuf(stdout, mybuffer, _IOLBF, 512);
    printf("hola\n");

    return 0;
}
```

El programa muestra esto en pantalla:`"‡òšv"`.

pero imprime `"hola"` si uso `fflush(stdout)` o `fclose(stdout)`. Aunque,
 ¿no debería el búfer volcarse a la salida automáticamente cuando encuentra el `'\n'` o cuando el programa termina?.

Usar el modo `_IOFBF` también da resultados iguales. Sólo `_IONBF`
parece imprimir bien el `"hola"`. Además, obtengo resultados similares en un archivo de texto.

No creo que esto me sirva me mucho pero solo me da curiosidad. Esperaría
que no imprimiera nada pero imprime estos caracteres aleatorios

Compilé este programa usando *gcc* en el *terminal*

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62292/discussion-on-question-by-jose-m-extrana-salida-usando-buferes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voy a transcribir la solución a la que hemos llegado entre @JuanM,  @PatricioMoracho y yo.

### Problema

Según explica @JuanM, el programa muestra correctamente solo la salida `"hola"` cuando llama a `fflush(stdout)` después del `printf()`. En cambio, si no llama a `fflush(stdout)` el programa imprime solo la basura `"‡òšv"` sin mostrar la cadena `"hola"`.

Como bien explica @PatricioMoracho, este problema no tiene nada que ver con el contenido que pueda tener el array `mybufer` antes de fijarlo como el búfer de `stdout`. De hecho, la función `setvbuf` inicializa dicho array como el nuevo búfer considerándolo como vacío desde el momento que se fija como nuevo búfer. Además, para asegurar que la basura no es el problema, @JuanM ha comprobado inicializando el contenido a `\0` y el problema seguía ocurriendo.

Como último dato a considerar inicialmente, @PatricioMoracho explica que en Windows (sistema donde está ocurriendo este problema porque en Linux el programa se ejecuta corrrectamente), la función `setvbuf()` no considera el modo `_IOLBF`, sino que termina tratándolo como el modo `_IOFBF`. Esto implica que el búfer es sólo volcado a `stdout` cuando se llena o cuando se llama explícitamente a `fflush(stdout)`, y nunca se vuelca automáticamente cuando aparece un salto de línea `'\n'`

### Solución

La causa de que ocurra este problema viene de la definición del búfer `mybufer` como una variable local de la función `main()`. Al definir el array como una variable local, el búfer queda definido dentro de la zona de memoria de la pila (*stack*). Por lo tanto, cuando la función `main()` finaliza, mueve la pila liberando todas las variables locales definidas. Antes de finalizar el programa, esa pila es usada por alguna rutina interna o alguna gestión de finalización interna, lo que provoca que la zona de memoria (la cual apuntaba a esa parte de la pila) fijada anteriormente como el búfer de `stdout` cambia a contenido basura. Una vez hecho esto, antes de finalizar el programa se vuelca el contenido del búfer (aunque no esté lleno) a `stdout` mostrando por pantalla los caracteres raros "‡òšv".

Las formas de solucionar este problema son las siguientes:

- **Definir el búfer como una variable global** (y `static` si solo va a ser usada en este archivo). Al finalizar la función `main()` y moverse la pila, no afecta a la zona de memoria reservada para la variable global donde se encuentra el búfer. El programa termina y vuelca el contenido del búfer correctamente. *(Mirar comentarios para el caso de usar una variables local `static` como búfer)*
- **Llamar a `fflush(stdout)`** (obligatorio si se usa una variable local como búfer) antes de acabar la función donde se declaró dicha variable. De esta forma se vuelca el contenido del búfer antes de que la variable local sea liberada al retornar de la función.
- **Usar `exit(0)`**. Esta solución es la menos correcta ya que `exit()` es mejor usarla en situaciones especiales. Al salir del programa con `exit(0)`, la pila no es restaurada como se hace cuando una función es finalizada con `return` liberando toda la memoria reservada en la pila (variables locales, argumentos, dirección de retorno, etc) durante la ejecución de la función. Por lo tanto, aunque el búfer esté definido como una variable local, con `exit(0)` es muy probable que la zona de memoria de la pila, donde está dicha variable local (búfer), no sea modificada y por lo tanto se vuelca el contenido correctamente al finalizar el programa.

Comment: Otra posible solución es definir la variable local `static` (haciendo que el contenido se mantenga entre llamadas a la función), pero como no lo he comprobado con @JuanM no lo he incluido.